# Inline code in blog contains raw markdown (backticks) instead of proper inline code

Tags: bug, markdown, blog, inline-code

In [the recent blog post on Rust & the White House](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/03/04/in-rust-we-trust-white-house-office-urges-memory-safety/?cb=1), there's some unescaped Markdown:

> (and Rust will let you explicitly mark code `unsafe`)

> But suppose you can’t rewrite your entire C or C++ codebase. There are ways to be memory-safe there, too. The snarky version is `[malloc(x) ( null )](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/na47wz/checklist_for_writing_memory_safe_c_code/)`. The helpful version, as [posted by user15919568 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081442/how-to-achieve-memory-safety-while-writing-c-code), includes the following:

Presumably, it should be `unsafe` and `malloc(x) ( null )`.

Can someone (SE staff) update the blog to correctly format the inline code?